# Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать?

Tags: javascript, функции

Напишите функцию sum,которая принимает неотрицательное число n и возвращает сумму чисел от 1 до n:
1 + 2 + 3 +...+n

Примеры

```
функция sum(0) должна возвратить 0; 
функция sum(1) должна возвратить 1; 
функция sum(2) должна возвратить 3; (т.к. 1 + 2 = 3);
функция sum(5) должна возвратить 15; (т.к 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15);
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const sum = (n) => n * (n + 1) / 2

console.log(
  sum(0),
  sum(1),
  sum(2),
  sum(5)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sum = number => {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = number; i > 0; i--) {
    result += i;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(sum(5));
```